# Buttons not being rendered on Different TabControl Alignments

Tags: vb.net, button, vb6, tabcontrol

I've migrated my application from vb6 to vb.net. In vb6 I had my tab controls button align to the bottom but when I converted it to vb.net the buttons not longer were being rendered. The button are only rendered when the alignment of the buttons is top.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 in Windows 10

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144846/tab-control-vertically-aligned-tabs-with-vertically-aligned-text

Comment: Add some image how this is look like. reference only for our answers